# Не работает js после загрузки его через ajax

Tags: ajax, joomla, form, javascript

По нажатию на кнопку отправки формы, при определенных условиях появляется `div`, всплывающий с еще одной формой и `js` к этой форме.

В таком случае `js` из этого `div`'а не выполняется.

В нем есть как и обычные функции (например, календарик всплывающий), так и `ajax`-валидация этой самой формы. Все это дело происходит на CMS Joomla и компоненте форм RS Form Pro. Фрагменты js:

```
<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
    rsf_CALENDAR.util.Event.addListener(
        window,
        "load",
        rsfp_init(
            1,
            { 
                layouts: Array('POPUP'),
                formats: Array('dd.mm.yyyy'),
                values: Array(''),
                extra: Array({})
            }
        )
    );
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var rsfp_ajax_root = ''
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    rsfp_addEvent(
        window,
        'load',
        function(){
            var form = rsfp_getForm(1);
            form.onsubmit = ajaxValidation;
        }
    );
</script>
```

Буду благодарен за любые соображения по этому вопросу. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

После подгрузки этого div'а, событие `window.load` никак не может произойти. Поэтому из всего приведённого кода выполнится только `var rsfp_ajax_root = ''`.

Поэтому надо, видимо сразу запускать коллбэки, как будтно window.load наступил (а так оно и есть). ТОлько поставить все эти подгружаемые скрипты в самый конец загружаемого блока. Чтобы они появились, когда вся разметка уже на месте.

```
    rsfp_init(
        1,
        { 
            layouts: Array('POPUP'),
            formats: Array('dd.mm.yyyy'),
            values: Array(''),
            extra: Array({})
        }
    )
    var form = rsfp_getForm(1);
    form.onsubmit = ajaxValidation;
```

Comment: Спасибо, но не работает и таким образом. Дело в том, что на странице присутствует еще одна такая форма, но стационарным образом. И вот календарик и тогда и сейчас появляется именно в стационарной. А после попытки отправить форму во всплывающем окне страница перегружается и все сообщения с ошибками есть в стационарной форме. 
Но даже и с выключенным дубликатом формы ничего не работает.